# MongooseJS Populate Array of refs within an array of refs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a mongoose object as follows:

```
var BoxSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    OwnerId: String,
    items: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}],
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
mongoose.model('Box', BoxSchema);

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    OwnerId: String,
    settings: {
        tools: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tool'}]
    },
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);

var ToolSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    type: {type: String},
    uses: [{type: String}]
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
mongoose.model('Tool', ToolSchema);
```

Now I do something like:

```
Box.find().populate('items settings.tools').exec(function(err, boxes){
    console.log(boxes);
});
```

I find that Items is getting populated well, but settings.tools within each item is not. How may I make it populate?